# How to install hyperledger explorer and integrate it to iroha?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer, hyperledger-iroha

hello and seen the repository documentation to install the explorer and is based on the  installation on fabric.

https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

This resource exists but gives little information about the installation process.

https://github.com/turuslan/iroha-explorer-backend

I am very grateful if there is any more detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/tree/iroha-integration/iroha) is the link to the instructions with Iroha. The links will soon be public on the main README of Explorer.